# How to keep replication in place when moving to a new SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

We have a clustered SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Enterprise edition in a passive clustered active-active environment. It has about 800 merge replication subscriptions on each server node. We are looking to upgrade to SQL Server 2016 Enterprise with the same clustering. All of the servers are currently virtualized on an ESXi 5.5 platform.

We are not able to do an in-place upgrade of the SQL Server instances and do not have the labor to redo the subscriptions for hundreds of independent locations. Is there any way to move the merge replication over in a more automated way with minimal end user disruption?  This is really hurting us and costing us $$$.

Also, is there any other a database can be replicated from a server to a client's PC without replication using something else that does propose issue?

As a note, the reason we replicate date is so our clients can still operate their business in the event they lose internet connection or there is a server issue.

Thanks

Comment: I recommend that you ask this on [dba.se]. Voting to migrate to that exchange.

Comment: Thank you.  I will